# Error: "Select-AzureSubscription Must specify a non-null subscription name"

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm receiving the above error when I select the Azure subscription name for an environment in my publish settings file.  The below is an example of the code I'm using in PS:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "D:\EnvironmentFile.publishsettings"
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Environment"
```

The second line is where I get the error; from what I see from examples and MS, this seems to be the correct sequence of events (note that the publish settings file is downloaded from Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile.

Note that I did try to edit each name to make sure they were different, but still got the same error.

Comment: Please check- Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Environment" is working for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue this morning when attempting to select an azure subscription in Powershell by SubscriptionName.

## Resolved following these steps:

Load powershell

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

Save the flle to C:\today.publishsettings

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile C:\today.publishsettings
```

Take note of the subscription ID required:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Id 123456-78911011-1213141516-1718-19201520
```

Hope that helps someone.